# What does "this movement" refer to?

Tags: meaning

What does ***this movement*** refer to? Feminist art or conceptual art?
The paragraph is titled '**Conceptual art, performance art, and feminist art(late 1960s-1970s)**,' so does it refer to feminist art?

> In the late 1960s, the art world was fractured into so many minor movements that tracking them all is difficult. In one of the most radical of these movements, artists believed that they didn’t need to produce any artwork at all (rather like Dada) but simply generate concepts or ideas. In reality, this conceptual art, as it’s known, is often a type of performance or “happening” that can be very spontaneous and audience-driven. Sometimes it’s simply writing on a wall. One early conceptual artist camped out with a coyote for a week in an art gallery to get people thinking about the treatment of Native Americans. Feminist art is linked with conceptual art in that it focuses on the inequalities faced by women and tries to provoke change. ***The movement*** has no set style. It might include a painting on canvas or a group of women dressed up in gorilla costumes crashing a public event to pass out pamphlets.

[Art History For Dummies](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=2M4Sm9vL5UcC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=it%20focuses%20on%20the%20inequalities%20faced%20by%20women%20and%20tries%20to%20provoke%20change.%20The%20movement%20has%20no%20set%20style.%20It%20might%20include%20a%20painting%20on%20canvas%20or%20a%20group%20of%20women&source=bl&ots=WuD3T-n8Ph&sig=ACfU3U3JQ5CzGRjueUa_am3P0eNSBQIbMg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKg9u6mJ_sAhXNUt4KHYBbBK8Q6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=it%20focuses%20on%20the%20inequalities%20faced%20by%20women%20and%20tries%20to%20provoke%20change.%20The%20movement%20has%20no%20set%20style.%20It%20might%20include%20a%20painting%20on%20canvas%20or%20a%20group%20of%20women&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph seems to link all three of conceptual, performance and feminist art:

> this conceptual art, as it’s known, is often a type of performance...

> Feminist art is linked with conceptual art...

Although "feminist" is the most recently mentioned before "the movement", I think the author means to link all three as a movement occurring in the 1960s and 1970s having "no set style". The last line of the paragraph mentions a group of women in gorilla costumes doing a performance event, which might be both "feminist" and "performance".

So, I think all three.